# Remove css property of :first-child

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

I need to remove or delete css property "padding-left:0" of a :first-child link. I have tried Inherit/Null/Unset but it doesn't do the job I intend, however, removal from HTML does the job but I can't find out the answer how to do it.

Here is my code:

HTML
    Here is the HTML:

```
<nav class="nav-menu nav-menu-additional-color page-scroll">
 <ul id="navigation" class="nav-menu-content">
   <li id="menu-item-3260" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-1290 current_page_item menu-item-3260">
   <a href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-3264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-3264">
   <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-3358" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3358">
   <a href="#">About</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul.nav-menu-content >li:first-child >a {
padding-left: 0
}
```

Comment: So you're trying to change the padding of a link but it's not working? What's your HTML look like?

Comment: Currently very unclear what you're asking. You've shown us some CSS code with a property set. No code concerned with the removal of CSS properties. Please edit the question.

Comment: I have added the HTML code. 
The thing is I can't manualy remove the css property from stylesheets as it is wordpress docs and I am using custom CSS/jQuery.
I am trying to remove the zeroed left padding which pushes the text of the link "Home" to the very left side and removing the "0" property would reset it back to center, however using "unset/inherit/initial" instead of 0 didn't achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you need is for the text *Home* to center, you can try apply your own css (padding) either via css or javascript, try this

```js
$('ul.nav-menu-content > li:first-child > a').css('padding-left', '50%');
```

```css
ul.nav-menu-content > li:first-child > a {
   padding-left: 50%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-menu nav-menu-additional-color page-scroll">
 <ul id="navigation" class="nav-menu-content">
   <li id="menu-item-3260" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-home current-menu-item page_item page-item-1290 current_page_item menu-item-3260">
   <a href="#">Home</a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-3264" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-3264">
   <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-3358" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-3358">
   <a href="#">About</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```